# Is there such thing as math.substring in java?

Tags: java, math, int, substring

Okay, I'm just getting curious. But I was wondering if there was such thing as a substring for numbers (math.substring ?), and then it would get the character(s) in the position specified.

Example (really poorly thought out one)

```
int number = 5839;
int example = number.substring(0,1)
println = example;
```

and then it displays 5?

Comment: Why don't you just use the rounding functions? In that example, `floor` followed by division by 1000 would give you 5

Comment: @ChrisW It won't be used for rounding :p I should've specified that, It would be used for comparing digits. I should've specified that.

Comment: The reason there's no substring operation for numbers is that numbers themselves are independent of way they're represented. If you want a substring of the base-10 representation, then make such a representation, as others have suggested. How would such a substring operation know you wanted base-10 (in ASCII, no less) and not base-2 (binary) or base-16 (hexadecimal) or base-64 or any number of others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int number = 5839;
String numString = Integer.toString(number);
String example = numString.substring(0,1)
int subNum = Integer.parseInt(example);
System.out.println(subNum);
```

Change it to a `String` first.
Here's a little function I wrote:

```
public static int intSubstring(int number, int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    String numString = Integer.toString(number);
    String example = numString.substring(beginIndex,endIndex)
    int subNum = Integer.parseInt(example);
    return subNum;
}
```

Or compressed:

```
public static int intSubstring(int number, int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    return Integer.parseInt((number+"").substring(beginIndex,endIndex));
}
```

Comment: Just checking to see if there was a way that was specific for numbers, But I guess not. Thanks :)

Comment: @Kalvin you could write a function like I did and call it, which would be kind of specific to `int` :)

Comment: You will get index array out of bounds each time as you are invoking a substring on an empty string. Add brackets to avoid this.

Comment: @FarhanSyed oh blah. I'm not thinking. :P Thanks

Comment: Well.. it is late in the day :P.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just convert it to a string, and then call `substring(0,1)`?...

```
int number = 5839;
int example = Integer.parseInt((number+"").substring(0,1));
```

Where calling `number+""` causes the JVM to convert it into a `String`, and then it calls `substring()` on it. You then finally parse it back into an `int`

Comment: You are missing brackets here: ((number+"").substring(0,1));

Comment: Are the brackets required? I understand that the JVM evaluates the `+""` first, to convert it to a String, before it attempts to call `substring()`. Of course, the brackets don't hurt :-)

Comment: I was the under the same impression until the day I realized I wasn't. Try running it. It will give you an error.

Comment: Isn't String.valueOf() faster?

Comment: Thanks @FarhanSyed, I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

No there is not. But you could possibly convert the integer to string and get the substring and again parse back to integer

Answer (score 2):

No there no such thing, but you can do the following:

```
String s = ""+number; //You can now use the Substring method on s;
```

Or if you just want to remove the last y digits:

```
number = (int)(number/Math.pow(10,y));
```

of if you want to keep only the last z digits:

```
number = number%(Math.pow(10,z)); // % means modulo
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is none. *int* is a primitive data type. You can however, accomplish your need with one statement.

```
Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(12345).substring(1, 2))
```

Comment: You would then have to parse the `String` back to an `int`.